# Share the last saved bitmap

Tags: android, layout, bitmap, save, share

I've been able to make a function which takes a photo of a layout and saves it to the phone.
But i cant manage to get to share it in the same function.
Here is my code:

```
public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
        v.draw(c);

        try {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "image.png" , "screenshot");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And i capture the photo with:

```
final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadBitmapFromView(view);
        }
    });
```

But i want to make that button to share the bitmap onClick.
Call on the last saved bitmap, and share it.
Is that possible?

Comment: What the problem with the sharing? Are you unable to retrieve the bitmap you want to share or what?

Comment: Where do you want to share, Its possible for sure

Comment: I wanna be able to make a share intent. And get the last saved bitmap as picture to share. 
Like this:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, b);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Dialog title text"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sold the problem. I made a uri of the bitmap and shared it with intent and it worked.

```
public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
    v.draw(c);

    try {
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "image.png", "screenshot");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/png");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return b;
}
```